# Powershell Active Directory Users to Multiple Groups using CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to assign Groups to users in Active Directory. In a simple case, its just case for doing a loop through a CSV file. However, In my circumstances, My csv is different. Example of csv is as followed.

> tjone,Time,Jones,Time Jones,tim.jones@home.ac.uk,Time Jones,Home Work, Manager, Finance, Staff, "OU=Groups,DC=Home,DC=ac,DC=uk",Finance;HR,P@ssw0rd

The Script is as followed:

```
#Read the CSV file
$PathofCSV = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\users.csv"

$Header = "sAMAccountName","givenName","sn","DisplayName","mail","cn","Company","Title","Department","OrgUnit","OU","Groups","Password"

$InfoCSV = import-csv $PathofCSV -Delimiter "," -Header $Header

ForEach ($user In $infoCSV)

{
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $user.Groups -Members $user.sAMAccountName
}
```

This is slightly different as you can see I'm trying to process the Groups Column which has more than one name and to make the matter worse, they are separated by the **";"**. So when I run the script, it see two name as one.

Question is, is it possible to separate those two names and processing them i.e. assigning two or more group names from one column.

I'm in an unfortunate position as I can't change the csv which I have received.

Any sort of help world be appreciated.

Comment: "a;b;c" -split ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [has already been pointed out in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641856/powershell-active-directory-users-to-multiple-groups-using-csv#comment66587283_39641856), use the `-split` operator:

```
foreach($user in $infoCSV)
{
    foreach($group in $user.Groups -split ';')
    {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user.sAMAccountName
    }
}
```

If this is PowerShell 2.0 (`-split` was introduced in version 3.0), you can use the `String.Split()` method:

```
foreach($user in $infoCSV)
{
    foreach($group in $user.Groups.Split(';'))
    {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user.sAMAccountName
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, Your solution worked. never thought it was that simle. thank you again.